# How do I get more results from Google Places / Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using google maps and I am trying out places API, but something makes me wonder...

If you load maps.google.com and go to Kuala Lumpur, then type "food" in the search-box, you will see hundreds of restaurants on the map. I would like to get these into my own maps.

Using the Places API, I have pretty much copied their example code:

```
function initialize() {
    var plat = 3.15;
    var plong = 101.7;
    var ppos = new google.maps.LatLng(plat, plong);
    var mapOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        draggable: false,
        zoom: 10,
        center: ppos
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), mapOptions);
    var request = {
        location: ppos,
        radius: '10000'
    };
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.search(request, callback);
}
function callback(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarker(results[i]);
        }
    }
}
function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        icon: place.icon
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent("<b>" + place.name + "</b><br/>" + place.vicinity);
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
}
```

When I execute this code, I do get results, but only very few and only major locations like a few malls and museums. So, How do I get all that beautiful data, that I see on Google's own map?

Comment: Can you post all of your code, maybe on JSFiddle, or have a link to a working site that demonstrates the problem? I just took the standard places search sample and set to your latitude and longitude and got plenty of results. I will say that categorization is off in Indonesia, if I try to do types:['store'] it doesn't work, but keyword works.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I have uploaded an example on http://www.raccoonmedia.net/places.html . To compare, please load maps.google.com, search for 'Bandar Manjalara' (It's a place in Malaysia) and type 'food', then you will see quite a few orange dots. But on my map, there's nothing.

Comment: By removing the types attribute, I do get results, but none are actually restaurants. It's a few companies, schools etc.
This can be seen on http://www.raccoonmedia.net/places2.html

Comment: try 'restaurant' and remove the quotes around the radius value as in
radius:1000

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything. I tried ['food'], [food], ['restaurant'], [restaurant] and removed the quotes from radius... But no luck

Comment: no, keyword just takes a string, not an array. var request = {
        location: ppos,
        radius: 10000,
        keyword: 'restaurant'
    };

Comment: Actually, that gives me better results. I am aware, that you can only generate 20 results at a time from Google's rules, and I get 20 Restaurants in the area with that keyword. It seems keyword is the way to go in this part of the world :) I just want to clarify though, that quotes on the radius and a string array for types is the suggested way to code as this basic Google example shows:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html

Comment: I am going to continue experimenting with keyword instead of types. I appreciate your help, if you copy your suggestion to an answer, I can close this thread (and hopefully help others with similar mysteries :)

Comment: String array for types is correct. However keyword is just string. Check out the type definitions in the API Reference: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PlaceSearchRequest. Quoted radius is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out there were a number of problems:
Categorization is broken in Inodesia, so using keyword instead solved the problem, as in:

```
var request= { 
  location: ppos, 
  radius: 10000, 
  keyword: 'restaurant' }
```

keyword takes a string rather than an array, and radius takes a number rather than a string. You can see a summary of the types for the request here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#PlaceSearchRequest